# preprocess_views_view not getting called

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-theming

Drupal 7,
Views,
Bootstrap theme sub theme in use

I have a views-view-table.tpl.php file in my sub theme and I am trying to preprocess some of the variables sent to this tpl. I created a function bootstrap_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) in my template.php and it is not getting called when I visit one of my views pages. Why would this be? Other preprocess functions are getting called from the same template file. I have tried flushing the cache.

```
function bootstrap_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
  dsm($vars);
  dsm("aaaa");
  die;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adam,

I'm assume you've tried all the regular things like clearing your cache, etc before expecting to see the change.

If yes, perhaps this old Drupal issue may be affecting your function: http://drupal.org/node/258089 (since your syntax looks fine).

Do you actually have a corresponding template file in your sub-theme?  If you place one in there (even just by copying and pasting the default one from the views module), does it solve your issue?

Let us know!